# C# External DLL

Tags: c#, dll, namespaces, .net-assembly

I have created an external DDL in C# to use in another project .
In one of the DLL functions I have the following lines of code :

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(Base).Assembly;
Type type = assembly.GetType(NameSpace + "." + ObjectType);
```

where "Base" is a dummy class (defined in the DLL) , "ObjectType" (type string) is the class name of any class inside the other project and "NameSpace" (type string) is namespace of the other project as well. 
When I try to call the DLL function while passing the "NameSpace" and "ObjectType" parameters I get the Type (i.e. type) as null .

My idea is to create one DLL and use in all projects rather than copying the files every time I create a new project.

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: "My idea is to create one DLL and use in all projects rather than copying the files every time I create a new project." So then just _reference_ the DLL from the other projects.  You shouldn't need to load types via reflection if you can reference the DLL at compile time.  It will make life _much_ harder for you.

Comment: We'd need much more information in order to answer this...     Indicate how the object type is declared, and what you are passing for NameSpace and ObjectType.

Comment: @Sinatr That's true when using `Type.GetType`.  `Assembly.GetType` does not need the assembly specified (since you;re calling in on an instance of `Assembly` that already knows that detail.

Comment: To debug this, look at the values of `Namespace` and `ObjectType` in the debugger, and look at the types available in the assembly in the debugger (look at `assembly.GetTypes()`).

Comment: @Sinatr No problem - just didn't want the OP heading in the wrong direction :)

Comment: this is how I defined the class in the other project . The DLL is referenced in the project . 
The type "Base" is defined in the DLL.

using DLL;
namespace test
{
    public class Nationality : Base
    {
        private int _ID;
        
        public int ID { get { return _ID; } set { _ID = value; } }
        
        public Nationality()
        {
            this._ID = 0;
        }
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

Is the assembly containing the type referenced? If not, did you load it manually?

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom("filepath")
```

After this, the type should be able to resolve.

Comment: Answers don't normally have that many question marks.  Don't guess please, use a comment to ask clarification from the OP.